# Xcode Instance member 'storage' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to create a reference to a firebase storage in my app but I keep running into the same error code: " Xcode Instance member 'storage' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'". I am new to using firebase storage, so I am following the guide on google's website. But i keep running into this error. Thank you in advance.

```
 import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
    // Create a storage reference from our storage service
    let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("Storagereference.url")
```

EDIT:

I fixed the initial problem and changed the code to:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage


 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var storageRef = FIRStorageReference()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

    let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://******************")

    let docxRef = storageRef.child("docx")

    let fileName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("fileName") as! String
    print(docxRef.child(fileName))
```

However, I now run into a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error" in the app delegate section when trying to run the app.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that the Swift importer got that as simply `FIRStorage()` (instead of `FIRStorage.storage()`), despite what the Google documentation says.